# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException

Tags: java

**Can not create a java class** for the respective Json string as **it is too big json file and dynamically it will change**.I would be glad if any one can post the solution. Need help....
Below is the sample code:..

```
public class rough {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsondata="{"data":[{"MsgType":"BTO","EventType":"901","Role":"Sender","Version":"2.3"}, {"MsgType":"BTO","EventType":"901","Role":"Sender","Version":"2.4"},{"MsgType":"BTO","EventType":"901","Role":"Sender","Version":"2.5"},{"MsgType":"BTO","EventType":"901","Role":"Sender","Version":"2.6"},{"MsgType":"BTO","EventType":"901","Role":"Sender","Version":"2.7"}]}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
        ValidationProfile profile=objectMapper.readValue(jsondata,ValidationProfile.class);
        System.out.println("profile:"+profile.toString());
    }

    public class ValidationProfile {
        public List<String> data;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you meant by `Can not create a java class for the respective Json string`?

Comment: Since the JSON text is dynamic, not static, use `readValue()` to parse into a `Map<String, Object>`, or use `readTree()` instead of `readValue()`.

Comment: as  a poc i have added sample code with a small json string, Actually the Json will be in file and its too big. So not possible to create class as data & adding the variables as public String MsgType .... and so on.

Comment: Andreas--- Thanks for your reply. if I use Map<String, Object>  the json will be in format as data as key and the full json will be as value. Need it in the form of a List<String>

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deserialize the JSON object as a JSON string. You can't do it.

As a simple fix (but it's not perfect) is changing your `ValidationProfile` class to:

```java
public static class ValidationProfile {
  public List<Map<String, String>> data;
}
```

A better approach is introducing corresponding classes for the entire JSON structure:

```
public static class ValidationProfile {
  private List<Event> data;

  // getters
}


public static class Event {
        
  @JsonProperty("MsgType")
  private String msgType;
  @JsonProperty("EventType")
  private String eventType;
  @JsonProperty("Role")
  private String role;
  @JsonProperty("Version")
  private String version;

  // getters
        
}
```

Comment: Can Not create a Class as the Json changes dynamically...& Need in form of List<String>

Comment: @Shubho The use `List<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: or more generally `List<Map<String, Object>>`

Comment: the Json String will not support any of the above collections

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "data" from the Json String at the beginning. worked for me.

JsonNode profile=objectMapper.readTree(jsondata);